# Can you add multiple content blocks to Grav CMS templates

Tags: php, content-management-system, grav

Just started using Grav CMS. I understand the concept of modular pages, but I really want to know if you can add multiple content blocks to a single page template. This way you could add two pieces of separate content to a single page from a single template.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the [Page Inject Plugin](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-page-inject) or follow [this example](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/1139#issuecomment-257035403):

`{{ page.find('/some/other.page').content }}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a file 'insert.html.twig' in your 'partials' folder. Put there just this:

```
{{ page.content|raw }}
```

Then you can put content of any page inside other page with:

```
{% include 'partials/insert.html.twig' with {'page': page.find('/link-to-your-page')} %}
```

If you don't want this page (the one you insert) to be in sitemap you have to hide it somehow so it's not indexable or in sitemap (not visible).

This is a method I've found somewhere and it works for me...